# CodeLite dark theme

Tags: opensuse, codelite

I just downloaded CodeLite 5.4 from YaST. It has everything that I want from an IDE. It has text predictions, autocomplete, and auto indent. I love it. It takes me back to Eclipse when I was using Windows. I could get my code done efficiently. There's only one one problem with it. I don't like the theme at all. White color schemes aren't good (especially for those of us who are up late coding) I've found this to be a problem in a lot of IDEs for Linux. How can I get this great IDE to look good?

Comment: "White color schemes aren't good (especially for those of us who are **up late coding**)" -> eye fatigue at night is a relevant though orthogonal issue. Any person (except people relying on exact colors like graphic artists) using a computer at night will benefit from [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) -- Windows/Mac users will use f.lux instead. Since I use redshift I've been able to use "white"-background themes apps late at night with comfort. Redshift is packaged in Debian and others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CodeLite 5.4 is a bit outdated. Did you try downloading latest CodeLite for OpenSUSE from [CodeLite website](http://codelite.org) ?

Once installed, you can select themes from (the main menu):
`Settings -> Colours and fonts -> <Your language>`

You should have a drop down which says: "Available themes"

Eran